# Visual Studio 2013 and Github

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2013, version-control

I just learned about source control and tried using it - so I activated for a project via VS2013 and it works locally, but then I tried to set up a repository at GitHub.com.
I used the default settings, which means https type connection (there is only https or ssh), but when I copied the url of the repo to VS to publish to it, VS showed the following error: "An error occurred while sending the request". 
I looked it up and almost all guides refer to opening a repo with an https type connection but there is no longer such option at gitHub.com, and I found the following article from Microsoft http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phkelley/archive/2013/10/20/git-network-operations-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx 
which explains why the error occurs and that some certificate needs to be added but I don't know how.
So my question is: is this the issue and how to solve it, or is there another way to use VS to upload the repo online to github.com or to some other place.

Also - as I only stared using VS2013 for source control - are there third party extensions that give a better experience for source control in VS2013 or is the built it git support the best it gets?

Comment: Did you clone the repository first? If not check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850445.aspx#remote_3rd_party_connect_clone

Comment: @Lukkha Coder - ok, I have cloned the repository and then when I wanted to publish I got a window of Windows Credentials that I filled with my account info on github.com and then I hit publish to the url of the repository I just cloned. But nothing happens - the commits are just sitting in the "Outgoing Commits" section for the last 10 minutes. What's missing? Thanks

Comment: Did you push the commits?

Comment: of course, i have hit the sync option but they are stuck at the "Outgoing Commits" Push section. they aren't syncing for some reason. By the way - I have set in the "Git Settings -> Settings" section the username that I use at github.com and the email address that I have set in github.com as my email. I am not sure if it's has anything to do with the actual sync process with github.com.

Answer (score 0):

> Also are there third party extensions that give a better experience for source control in VS2013 or is the built it git support the best it gets?

Default git support in vs2013 is not very good and easily understandable even for an experienced git user :-(

I highly recommend to use one if the 3 tools: gitextensions, sourcetree or github client.

The support of git in VS 2015,  even with the github extension, even if it's better, is not enough...

Comment: What capabilities so those tools give me that i don't get with the default git support.

Comment: Rebase (and rebase --into) , staging area, stashing, staging chunk of files, seeing the DAG ( and better understanding branches !), overall better understanding of git when you learn (because Git in VS is messy) and a lot of good things everywhere... As an advanced git user, I found git use in VS to be difficult and I always have to think hard to find how/where they have implemented some features to do the things I want to do :-( ...let imagine if you are a first time user!

Comment: since you are a git expert can you assist me in the issue I have had with syncing the repository online - I have described it in message to @Lukkha Coder at the top of this thread. Thanks